# Codeigniter form without any ajax work in the desktop but fail in mobile

Tags: codeigniter, csrf

I am working in an application using Codeigniter 2.1.4 and I have a simple login form and I am not using any ajax to submit or load the form ('data-ajax' => 'false'). Also I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 to give the site a mobile look as it will be accessed most from mobile devices.

The issue I am having is that in the PC or Mac the login form work and I can access the private section of the site, but if I try accessing the site from a mobile device (iPad and iPhone) I keep getting the error:

> **An Error Was Encountered**
>
> The action you have requested is not allowed

A lot of google search results suggest issues with the CSRF feature in CI 2.x with forms using ajax and even when disabling the CSRF feature in the config.php file the issue is not solved. I even tested the application without the jQuery Mobile library without luck.

> **Note:** The odd thing is that I tested the app in Google Chrome for the iPhone and it work like a charm, but I tested it a Samsung Galaxy
>   III and it gave me the same error.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but maybe it will help you find one. That message is definitely CSRF. The way CI does its CSRF is by embedding a token in each form with a value that must match that stored in a cookie. using `form_open()` automatically generates a hidden field in the form with the token. CSRF is only applied to POST requests, and why it would still be tripping you up when it appears to be turned off is something you'll have to dig to discover. Sorry if this isn't much help, but maybe a something here will put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have even connect the iPhone and the iPad and switch on the web console to debug in Safari and I can see the hidden field in the form on the mobile device before submitting the form and getting the error.